# Scala refactoring in IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Is refactoring Scala code in intellij IDEA broken?  I've tried several time to move a class to a different package and it mutilates it every time.  (Am using the SBT plugin and the community edition of IDEA)

Comment: Does the community edition include all the refactoring capability?  I've only used the full-featured edition, so I don't know.

Comment: @duffymo - yes, the Scala plugin is independent of the "enterprise" edition. It's open sauce and includes contributions from the likes of SO's vey own *retronym*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's mostly broken. http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/291622?tstart=30

Comment: Is this still true in 2018? I can not make move refactoring work for me even now.